# How do I compile C++ file using the Eigen Library?

Tags: c++, compilation, static-libraries

I'm currently following this [Eigen: Getting Started](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/GettingStarted.html) to try to compile my C++ file using the Eigen Library but I'm running into a bunch of errors. My current directory contains my `main.cpp`, `network.h` and the Eigen Library which contains a directory called Eigen and a bunch of other folders. The guide says to just put in the path to folder, containing the header files. I'm currently using
`g++ -I eigenLibrary/Eigen main.cpp -o network` to compile, but I keep getting the error `fatal error: 'Eigen/Dense' file not found #include <Eigen/Dense>`.
I'm trying implement the code in this [tutorial](http://richard-alan-herbert.com/training-a-simple-hopfield-network-in-c/)
 . How can I make sure I'm linking the libraries in the right format. I don't have much experience with C++

EDIT:
I've tried copying the Eigen subdirectory into `/usr/local/include` and running
`g++ -I /usr/local/include/Eigen/Dense main.cpp -o main` to no success.

Answer (score 2):

Please include the Eigen library path as follows:

`g++ -std=c++11 -I /usr/include/eigen3/ fileName.cpp`

Answer (score 0):

Try -I eigenLibrary instead of -I eigenLibrary/Eigen in your command line

Comment: I've tried that previously. I keep getting `./network.h:17:21: error: expected ';' at end of declaration MatrixXd weights{ MatrixXd::Zero(i, j) }; `

Comment: so you tried that and you got past the problem with 'Eigen/Dense' file not found #include <Eigen/Dense>?

Comment: Yeah I did. But now I'm getting an error in this line of code - 
`MatrixXd weights{ MatrixXd::Zero(i, j) }; return weights;`

Comment: I don't understand why you down voted my answer when it actually solved the question you asked...

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer. I'm not sure who did. Also, I haven't fixed my code yet. Haven't been able to fix the error i mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

Eigen3 headers is by default installed under `/usr/include/eigen3` directories
To compile a program using Eigen3

1. a solution suggested by `@Arjun Kumar` could be used
2. to save tedious typing every time during compiling, a symbolic link inside `/usr/local/include` can be added to point to `/user/include/eigen3` be made:

   ```
   sudo ln -s /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen /usr/local/include/Eigen
   ```

and then compile the program without any flags like:

```
    g++ -std=c++11  fileName.cpp
```